# Abnormal inline-block positioning after adding content

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm working with inline-block elements when I encountered this issue. Below is the expected layout of the elements. It's just simple cards with a pseudo element positioned absolutely after it.

**Expected Layout:**

[image]

```css
.deck-list-container{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.2);
}

.deck-list-item {
  padding: 5pt;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10pt;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 10rem;
}

.deck-list-item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(0.5rem);
  height: 3rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 25%, 100% 0, 100% 98%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="deck-list-container">
  <div class="deck-list-add"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
</div>
```

However, for some reason. **The layout breaks when I add an element inside the div.** I've been analyzing chrome dev tools for the problem for a long time now but it seems like I'm stuck. Anyone have any idea what's happening?

**Issue:**
[image]

**I've tried the following:**

- removing :after pseudo element
- adding box-sizing: border-box
- removing position: relative

Comment: The first list item class is add, you have not mentioned the style for deck-list-add

Comment: @Soheb Sorry! I didn't think it was relevant. A fellow user already pointed out the problem though. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `vertical-align` property of `.deck-list-item` to something other than the default of `baseline`. E.g. `top`:

```css
.deck-list-container{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.2);
}

.deck-list-item {
  padding: 5pt;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10pt;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 10rem;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.deck-list-item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(0.5rem);
  height: 3rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 25%, 100% 0, 100% 98%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="deck-list-container">
  <div class="deck-list-add"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item">text</div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
  <div class="deck-list-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why has vertical-align to be changed ?

Comment: @frederic Because the default vertical-align value for inline elements is baseline, which is causing the alignment problem.

Comment: _how_ is it causing the alignament problem

Comment: It worked! Can you elaborate on why baseline is breaking the layout. Aren't they all the same height and fit the same line box.

Comment: @frederic The `.deck-list-item` elements without content don't change their vertical alignment, but adding content, like in my example, makes the default baseline take effect, moving them downward in this layout. You an read all about how vertical-align works at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Oh! Got it. Thanks a lot.